# MalformedURLException no protocol. How to fix?

Tags: java, audio, malformedurlexception

So I have this Code:

```
 import java.applet.Applet;
 import java.applet.AudioClip;
 import java.net.URL;

 public class SoundTest {
     public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {

    URL url = new URL("Sprites/Omni's Tones/New tones/bubblespawn_01.wav");
    AudioClip clip = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
    AudioClip clip2 = Applet.newAudioClip(url);
    clip.play();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
    clip2.loop();
    Thread.sleep(20000);
    clip2.stop();

    System.out.println("end");
     }
 }
```

An error Appears:

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.net.MalformedURLException: no protocol: Sprites/Omni's Tones/New tones/bubblespawn_01.wav
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:586)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:483)
at java.net.URL.<init>(URL.java:432)
at com.edu4java.minitennis7.SoundTest.main(SoundTest.java:10)
```

How do I fix this? Thank you!
 It seems that I need to add more lines to my code,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are running it inside the Applet then try with [Applet#getCodeBase()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getCodeBase%28%29) and [Applet#getDocumentBase](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/applet/Applet.html#getDocumentBase%28%29)

```
URL url = getDocumentBase();

AudioClip audioClip = getAudioClip(url, "music/abc.wav")
```

---

If it's running in a standalone application then choose one based on music file location:

```
// Read from same package
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("abc.wav");

// Read from music folder parallel to src in your project
File file = new File("music/abc.wav");

// Read from src/music folder
URL url = getClass().getResource("/music/abc.wav");

// Read from src/music folder
InputStream inputStream = getClass().getResourceAsStream("/music/abc.wav");
```